# GetExternalLoginInfoAsync returns null for AddMicrosoftAccount

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

In my program I have

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = "...";
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = "...";

    microsoftOptions.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
    microsoftOptions.TokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/v2.0/token";

    microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
    microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
    microsoftOptions.Scope.Add("email");
});
```

And I've set it up in Azure.

The new login button appears on the `/Identity/Account/Login` page and the login process proceeds. The callback URL seems to have to be `/signin-microsoft`, but it proceeds to `Identity/Account/ExternalLoginCallback`, where I was *expecting* to obtain a claims identity from which I could set up the local user account.

However,

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

returns `null`.

In the `.Request` I can see a cookie names `idsrv.external` but the `.User` has no claims.

What is wrong? This should work!

Comment: Don't know why you're setting all the endpoints and even use anything related to IdentityServer. You actually don't need any of that. [Here's the only thing I needed to do](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Startup.cs#L220) (which ofc can be done in the `AddMicrosoftAccount` call too

Comment: **Supported account types** is set to **All Microsoft account users**. And off course the authorized redirect url you need to add in Azure is like `https://localhost:12345/signin-microsoft`

Comment: Ah and perhaps you should post your middleware pipeline too. It should be `UseAuthentication`, `UseRouting`, `UseAuthorization`, `UseEndpoints`

Comment: What's your problem with IdentityServer? (The project is an installation of IdentityServer that will provide access tokens to our client side apps to access our APIs.) I just wanted to turn on AzureAD. The URLs are required because the default ones don't work -- something about 'tenants' in Azure. There is nothing unusual about the middleware stack; normal IdentityServer is working just fine -- it's just disappointing that it's not possible to add AzureAD external provider.

Comment: Oh I see... Perhaps you can take a look at [these templates](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates/tree/master/src/content). They work fine. All you need to do is fill out the AppId and AppSecret in the appsettings.Development.json

Answer (score 0):

The default value is broken.

Changing

```
microsoftOptions.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
```

to

```
microsoftOptions.SignInScheme = "Identity.External";
```

has made it work.

Comment: I can tell you why, because the external login code has nothing to do with identity server. So `IdentityServerConstants` do not come into play.